# /etc setting to ping as non-root freely

Tags: networking, ping, etc, proc, sysfs

Since some not long time ping stopped working as non-root (I'm not sure if it distro-wide or maybe it is my custom kernel). The ping is fixed by this command:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ping_group_range="0 1000"
```

But the problem is I cannot add it to `/etc/sysctl.conf` because it looks like it is overriden in boot later. If someone fixed the same problem please share your knowledge.

Comment: what do you have in `/usr/lib/sysctl.d/50-default.conf`? I have `-net.ipv4.ping_group_range = 0 2147483647` and indeed `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ping_group_range` gives `0       2147483647`. Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: What does this tell us? `ls -al /usr/bin/ping`

Comment: @DougSmythies No such file, no such setting. Which package it's from? Please post an answer.

Comment: If there are problems with your bootup, it is always `systemd`. 249.11 has `50-default.conf` while 251.4 don't have it. Either I should downgrade or get the copy of the file, will decide later.

Comment: @DougSmythies Thanks!